# API client that can sync via git and costs nothing

Tags: gratis, api, file-synchronization, git

My colleagues and I maintain a collection of (REST) requests, that we share via git.
We were happy users of **Postman** until they removed the import feature.
Our intended replacement **Insomnia** technically offers that feature, but the export is one JSON file in one line, with makes syncing via git very annoying. On top of that, the export contains ids with change with every export, so meaningful git diffs are not possible even if the export is formatted.
So we are looking for alternatives, but there are just too many options to analyse them all properly and they may not all last very long, so I believe a question here where answers can be updated is useful.
We are looking for an API client that **must**:

- have a GUI where requests can be edited and organized
  *we are technical but not that technical*
- be stable -> can be used productively now
- store each request in its own file
  *so we can comfortably sync via git or other file based sync technologies (e.g. nextcloud)*
- not be expected to force users to sync via their own cloud sync in the near future
- be free to use
  (for what its worth, we have IntelliJ licences)
- support

  - private variables, so secrets can be defined by each user and interpolated into requests, but the secrets are not synced.
  - public variables, so multiple URLs can be used in the same request and these values can be synced.
- be able to send REST requests

explicitly **optional**:

- open source
  *even an open source app like Insomnia can move towards the cloud, and if a closed source app offers everything we need we want to consider it*
- testing capabilities
  as long as we see the response to our requests we are fine

Comment: "not be expected to force users to sync via their own cloud sync in the near future" - you should delete or reword that bullet points as I doubt there are any clairvoyants here. I guess you instead mean "not publicly announced that they'll switch to cloud model in the near future"

Answer (score 0):

"[bruno](https://www.usebruno.com/)"?

There was a discussion on Hacker News recently: [Tell HN: Postman update removes all your stuff if you refuse to create account](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=37792690)

In the comments people mentioned a tool "[bruno](https://www.usebruno.com/)" , ([github](https://github.com/usebruno/bruno/discussions/269)) that might do what you need.
Admittedly, I haven't tried it myself yet.

In this [issue thread on github](https://github.com/usebruno/bruno/discussions/269) there is a table with pros and cons of similar apps.

Answer (score 0):

You could try very popular and open source [hoppscotch](https://github.com/hoppscotch/hoppscotch). It definitely has saving collections to a file, but I don't remember its structure. Other features you listed are also supported.